# 3D window creation and plotting in Ocean for Petrel

Tags: ocean, petrel

I am trying to draw a 3D plot in Petrel where I am trying to plot some volume data using OpenInventor.

I am doing this through a custom domain object. But I dont want to select an item from the input tree. I want my algorithm should automatically open a 3D window and do the plotting for me using data from that class.

How do I go about doing this?

I have a class with the data and the corresponding OIV factory class for plotting.

Please help. How do I create a cube and plot data automatically?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are not interested in integrating with the existing 3D window.

I suggest that you host your own OIV Examiner Viewer in your own dialog. Then you do not need to create data objects, render factories, etc.

If you do want to participate in the existing 3D window you need to do:

```
CoreSystem.Services.Register(typeof(MyData), typeof(IWindow3DRenderer), new MyRenderer());
```

and

```
var data = new MyData()
PetrelProject.Inputs.Add(data);
PetrelProject.ToggleWindows.Show(data);
```

Comment: I want to plot it in a Petrel 3D window only but don't want to do it through a custom object. Rather I would have like it to get some data values and plot it on the fly.